# SOQL and SQL joins

Tags: soql

Good Morning

From what I can see joins are not available in the traditional sense with SOQL.  I think I need to use "relationship".  I have not had any success so far and want to confirm I'm going in the right direction as this query is critical for a time sensitive project.

The issue is that I need to retrieve all postal codes on a Case that correspond to a series of values provided for a specific field(social media handle) of the Social Persona. I need to be able to pass a series of social media handle as a parameter and return the corresponding postal code for each.  Sounds simple enough but like I said everything I tried has been unfruitful and I'm not convinced I'm using the correct approach.

Any direction someone can provide would be very appreciated and an example would be ideal of course.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: This will likely need to a be a few queries depending on the specifics.  Is the Social Media Handle Field on the case a text field that takes a single social media handle?  When you say postal code associated with the case, do you mean the postal code of the contact or account on the case, or is the postal code coming from somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you @sfdc_ninja for your response.  I was really hoping this could be accomplished with a single query.  So yes the Social Media Handle on the Case is unique for the case. The postal code is on the case but I know exactly where it's coming from. Here is the simple SOQL I can use to retrieve both the postal code and social persona from the Case:

Comment: *** The 5 minute limit on the site prevented me for better editing my response above ***
 
 The above should say the Social Media Handle is **not** on the Case but on the Social Persona.
 The Social Media Handle is unique to the Social Persona(and not available directly on the Case).

Here is the SOQL I used to retrieve a single Postal Code for a given Social Media Handle:  
 
 SELECT Postcode_and_number__c,  #####__SocialPersona__c
 FROM Case WHERE #####__SocialPersona__c in (SELECT Id FROM SocialPersona WHERE Name = 'aUniqueSocialHandle')

Comment: Where for the comment above,  ##### blurs specific company details and 'aUniqueSocialHandle' could be a twitter handle for example.